# cURL returns wrong characters

Tags: php, curl, character-encoding

I have JSON object

```
{"state1":"http://www.furry.cz/images/spot_public.gif","state2":"http://www.furry.cz/images/spot_readonly.gif","Id":"332","Name":"Co pr%av%e poslouch%ate?","Section":"Hlavn%i","Posts":"5473","Readable":1,"User":"Šroubek","Time":"00:25 23.07.2014","New":0}
```

on external server and I'm downloading it with cURL

```
<?php
   $curl = curl_init("http://dagl.6te.net/fcz/api.php?c=forum");
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
```

and instead of `Šroubek` it returns `�roubek`.

I also tried converting it with `iconv`, by setting

```
header("Content-Type: text/html, charset=UTF-8")
```

and by

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: text/plain, charset=UTF-8'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page that you are trying to download data in ANSI your in UTF-8, then there is an error in the encoding. In addition, you gain data from the page dagl.6te.net that downloading a page furry.cz in ANSI and there does not change encoding .. Therefore accented characters Replacin original to further the application to switch back to the characters.

Example:
Š = %S
in appliaction i change it back to Š

**EDIT: Fixed in API.**